# How do I convert a string to a Array (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have a string that is in a format of a Array, but I need it to be a Array and it has to be a string.

Example Of Data (**string**):

```
[{"itemName": "LimitedName", "itemName": "ID", "itemClassName": "ClassName", "MaxAllowed": 1000}]
```

I need it to become an actual array and be able to add more columns to it as well.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.parse(someString)`